# Куда положить dll?

Tags: dll

Я написал программу. На других компьютерах требует msvcr100d.dll.
Я его скачал. Вот вопрос: куда его надо теперь положить?

Comment: В папку с программой либо в `c:\windows\system32\`.

Comment: Лучше положить в 2 места. %System32% и в папку с программой, которая требует DLL`ку

Comment: лучше положить в каждую директорию, на всякий случай :-) Дубликат вопроса http://hashcode.ru/questions/98120/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F же! Если не устраивает решение с развертыванием редистрибутабла - укажите это четко.

Answer (score 4):

Правильный подход - установить пакет: [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5555). Или добавить его установку в свой собственный проект.

Comment: В Redistributable Package никогда не будет отладочных версий DLL. Отладочные версии не являются redistributable.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы действительно уже *написали* вашу программу, то вам в первую очередь следует откомпилировать ее начистовую, т.е. в конфигурации Release, чтобы она использовала "чистовую" версию стандартной библиотеки. В частности: `msvcr100.dll`, которая поставляется в рамках Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package.

Ни о какой `msvcr100d.dll` речи быть не может и скачивать ее вы ниоткуда не должны. Если вашей программе понадобился `msvcr100d.dll`, значит вы занимаетесь какой-то ерундой. Прекратите ваши бессмысленные попытки запускать вашу программу "на других компьютерах" и начните с правильной компиляции.

Comment: Ну может уже не занимается ерундой, 7 лет прошло все-таки)

Comment: @insolor: Сейчас он, небось, ищет `msvcp140d.dll`. Название другое, но суть та же...

Answer (score 0):

Если положить все нужные dll в папку с программой, то она, скорее всего, успешно запустится.